# Iterating through strategy design pattern

Tags: asp.net, ruby, algorithm, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have a list of algorithms that I want to run on a dataset. For example, say my dataset is a list of addresses. I need to check the validity of the addresses but I have several different algorithms for validating. Say I have `validation_one` and `validation_two`. But in the future I will need to add `validation_three`, `validation_four`, etc. I need ALL of the validations to run on the address list, even the new ones when they get added.

Is there a design pattern that fits into this? I know strategy is for *selecting*  an algorithm but I specifically need a way to apply all the algorithms on the dataset.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This sounds like the Chain of Responsibility where all handlers in the chain accept the request and pass it to the next handler.

Comment: ...which is a Composte. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern note that the Component interface as an operation() defined.

Comment: The Chain-of-Responsibility isn't the Composite pattern.  The composite pattern always implies a tree structure of parent/child objects conforming to the same interface where clients make calls only upon the parent object.  For example, a View, Pane, and Widget class may all implement a Drawable interface with a Draw() method.  A single View may compose multiple Panes which may compose other Panes which may compose Widgets.  The client doesn't care how big the tree is.  It merely calls viewInstance.Draw() which draws itself and instructs each of its children to draw themselves, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have not stated a language.. but assuming it has generics.

Given a `DataSet<T>`

Assuming also that there is no cross validation required (i.e. each T can be validated entirely by its own data)

Declare a validation Strategy, with a single method.

```
IValidate<T>{bool validate(T item);}
```

validation_one, validation_two…. Will implement this strategy

Have a `List<IValidate<T>>` which you can add and remove implementations to.

Foreach item in the dataset call each strategy in the list.

It’s then your choice to how you deal with failures.

Comment: I've done this kind of thing and the only thing I would add to what @yoztastic said is (in production code) to make the validation method a bit more verbose by having it provide additional error details. You typically don't want to know if the dataset failed, you want to get back a list of know which rows failed, and which rule or rules caused the fail, and a human readable message. "The field 'XYZ' was invalid. The error was 'Out of Range'. The reason was 'This field must be greater 0 and less than 365'."   Just a suggustion, but build support for this at the start!

Comment: Absolutely agree @tcarvin. I would populate a Map<T,List<string>> where list contains human readable explanation of each strategy failure. Any T's not found in the map are valid by their absence.

Comment: It is an implementation detail, but I created an Error collection and passed that as part of the validation signature.  On any validation error, the `Validate` method implementation added an error object that stored these details.  To see if the whole operation was validated clean it was as simple as `if (errors.Count == 0)`.  Made it easy to present all the error deatils to the user too by dumping the error collection to a grid.

Answer (score -1):

[Composite.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

Which is basically what the two other answers equate to.

The first answer is an implementation of COmposite. The second one is usign Chain of Rersponsibility as a Composite.

Comment: No, it's not just Composite. Composite is a structural pattern which organizes objects in tree-like structures. There's no notion of "processing" the tree, you need an additional pattern like Visitor to introduce "processing". Your answer is then not complete if it doesn't mention the Visitor. On the other hand, Chain of Resp is a behavioral pattern which is built up around the notion of processing requests by handlers. Regards.

Comment: Composite is absolutely a way to process the tree (or list) of similarily typed items that are in the composite. Why else have a composite at all? Visitor is only used if you want to inject the algorithm in the composite. Composite is usually classified as a structural pattern, but the core concept is that you can make many act like one - structurally and behaviorally. Chain of Resp. mainly differs from Composite in the conditional forwarding and optional deferring handling of the message/request.

Comment: The Composite pattern is a structural organization where all items used to compose a single object conform to the same interface in a tree structure.  Looping over a collection of items that all conform to an interface and calling a method isn't the Composite pattern.